# onclick method applied to image object results in transition to "no" page

Tags: javascript, html

I try to make an image display in a popup window when a user click on it.
The code given below performs this function but after instead of the original page, transition to {server_path/no} "page" occurs. How to avoid this transition?

```
 <html><head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function show_popup (url,name) {
newpop=window.open(url,name,menubar='no',location='no',scrollbars='yes',resizable='yes');
newpop.focus();
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<img src=image.jpg height=50 onclick=show_popup("image.jpg","newpop")></img>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to make a change to 'location'. try and set it to:

```
..,location='{your image path}',..
```

Comment: yes, it works, actually I don't need that 'location' keyword at all. Thanks   ne0lithic_coder & Dr.Kameleon

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to look at that weird :

`location='no'`

and change it?

Answer (score 0):

Use the correct syntax:

```
window.open(url,name,"menubar=no,location=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes");
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change the parameters to:

```
newpop=window.open(url,name,"menubar='no',location='no',scrollbars='yes',resizable='yes'");
```

window.open only take 4 parameters:

```
window.open(URL,name,specs,replace)
```

For the specs, it is a string, so add "" to it.